# nextjs 13 api call does not work after production build using axios

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am using app folder in nextjs 13 which has my server code. In the page.tsx file in server code i am fetching api(using axios) from strapi which is hosted on same server and showing data from api request.

Expected result is every time route matches for this page axios api request needs to be called and which works as expected in dev. However once i push code to server and do production build(NODE_ENV=production npm run build), i will not get updated code in api on visiting page. It does show data from api but data is what api served at the production build time.

things i tried:

1. setting  cache: "no-store",

   const axios_instance = axios.create({
   baseURL: process.env.BACKEND_API_URL,
   timeout: 1000,
   headers: {
   Authorization: "Bearer " + process.env.STRAPI_BEARER_TOKEN,
   cache: "no-store",
   },
   });

   export default axios_instance;